# Get a limited number of DISTINCT fields ordered by some value when you can't ORDER BY unselected columns

Tags: sql, hiveql

## Question

I have a table `tmpcalc` in Hive which looks like this:

```
| country_name | unemp        |
-------------------------------
| Latvia       | 22           |
| Spain        | 24           |
| Spain        | 21           |
| Austria      | 3            |
| Lithuania    | 20           |
| Belgium      | 5            |
| Greece       | 21           |
```

I want to craft a query to retrieve the name of the 3 distinct countries which are associated to the highest `unemp` values:

```
Spain
Latvia
Greece
```

## What I have tried

Normally I would expect this to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(country_name)
FROM tmpcalc
ORDER BY unemp DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

However, HiveQL does not allow you to order by values for which you are not selecting, so that's a no-go.

---

I normally work around that issue with something like this:

```
SELECT country_name
FROM (
    SELECT country_name, unemp
    FROM tmpcalc
    ORDER BY unemp DESC) a
LIMIT 3;
```

This returns the list of all countries sorted in descending order. However, we have the issue that "Spain" is duplicated in that list, as it has two of the highest 3 `unemp` values:

```
Spain
Latvia
Spain
```

---

Unfortunately, simply adding DISTINCT around the outer `country_name` field does not work, as it screws up the order and now returns three countries in alphabetical order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(country_name)
FROM (
    SELECT country_name, unemp
    FROM tmpcalc
    ORDER BY unemp DESC) a
LIMIT 3;
```

```
Austria
Belgium
Greece
```

Comment: How does a country end up in your original list twice?

Comment: What if you add limit after `ORDER BY unemp DESC` in the subquery  like  `ORDER BY unemp DESC limit 1000` ?

Comment: @JeffUK These are unemployment levels in different countries through the years. The original table had an extra "year" attribute in each tuple, but I omitted it to keep the question concise.

Comment: Could you not group the table first using max(), then you have a list of distinct countries and values?

Comment: @JeffUK That's eventually what I ended up doing :)

Comment: @ErgestBasha Then I get the first 1000 countries in the subquery, with duplicates. The problem persists: as soon as I try to remove the duplicates from outside the subquery via DISTINCT or something like that, the order is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest answer I have found:

```
SELECT country_name
FROM (
   SELECT country_name, MAX(unemp) AS unemp
   FROM tmpcalc
   GROUP BY country_name
   ORDER BY unemp DESC LIMIT 5
);
```

The important bit is to remove all entries from one country except for its highest one (through `MAX` and `GROUP BY`) before applying the limit.